# How to grab an id number in output from Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab a specific ID from a string, I have tried just doing replace(), I tried a few things with regex but I can't seem to get it.  How can I just grab that ID number?  Also the number is displayed twice so I only need the one.

I couldn't get it to work with regex because it's not actually a string it's type "<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>"

The output is like this

```
<span class="New_Link" id="tid_5785847"><a href="showthread.php?tid=5785847">Some text here?</a></span>
```

Comment: how about selecting `a` then using `.attrib['href']` to get the value? then separate by `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it is my variant

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '<span class="New_Link" id="tid_5785847"><a href="showthread.php? 
tid=5785847">Some text here?</a></span>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
span_attribute = soup.find('span')
id_value = span_attribute.get('id')  # it is your ID from id="tid_5785847"
id_value = id_value.replace('tid_', '')  # replace tid_
print(id_value)  # print only 5785847
```

Comment: There we go!  Not sure how I didn't think of this.  Clearly I need to focus more on learning Python because I was trying to figure this out for at least two hours.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: @PythonC, in this case, it is not Python. You should understand how bs4 work and how to work its components.
Good luck :)